# Problem with typesetting maths content in an unusual font in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode

I want to typeset math in different font called Antykwa Torunska, which supports maths. Unfortunately, when using it in `beamer` the math font is switched to the standard math font of `beamer`. How can I change this behaviour?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Mathekram:
\usepackage{amssymb, amstext, amsmath}
% Font:
\usepackage[math]{anttor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Testframe}
   This is fine: 1234567890, \textit{x}, \textit{p}, \textit{t}\\
   This is not fine: $1234567890$, $x$, $p$, $t$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When I change `beamer` to `article` it works fine.

Comment: I can confirm this on TeXLive 2012 under mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` to your preamble or use the `professionalfonts` class option, in order to suppress any font replacements performed by `beamer`.

Comment: This works fine, except when you use \SI{30}{\cm} in the align environment , than it gives the standard beamer font again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need to add the `[professionalfont]` option to your `\documentclass` command. See section 18.1 of the [beamer documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) for details.